# Django rest framework: CreateAPIView, when the data is stored I want to use the primary key

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm pretty new to django and python and could use some help. Currently an API-call can be made to my app, which stores the data. But I need to do some business logic after the storage. How do I do this.

my view:

```
class ProcList(generics.CreateAPIView): 
    queryset = Proc.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ProcSerializer
    permission_classes = (IsAdminOrReadOnly,)
    lookup_url_kwarg = 'proc_id' # primary key
```

my serializers:

```
class BlobSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer): # Child (Old Avatar)
    key = serializers.CharField()
    value = serializers.CharField()  
    class Meta:
        model = Blob
        fields = ('pk', 'key', 'value')

class ProcSerializer(WritableNestedModelSerializer): # Father (Old profile)
    blobs = BlobSerializer(many=True)    
    class Meta:
        model = Proc
        fields = (
            'pk',
            .... Hidden/removed for length purpuse
            'service',
            'country_code',
            'blobs'
        )
```

my model (only the Proc-one, since the Blob-model is not important)

```
class Proc(models.Model): # Father (Old profile)
    MY_SERVICES = (
        ("em", 'Email'),
        ("sm", 'SMS'),
        .... Hidden/removed for length purpuse
    )
    proc_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, help_text="Primary key")
    service = models.CharField(max_length=2, choices=MY_SERVICES, blank=True, default='mc', help_text='What service is desired, MyChoice is default')
    .... Hidden/removed for length purpuse
    country_code = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, name='created_at')
```

My desired outcome is that the API-post-call, stores to the Proc and Blob model as they do now. Given what the "service"-variable is, I want to pass on the primary key to another mode. Ex. Sms.proc(proc_id)

Example (ugly, sorry =)

```
class ProcList(generics.CreateAPIView): 
    queryset = Proc.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ProcSerializer
    permission_classes = (IsAdminOrReadOnly,)
    lookup_url_kwarg = 'proc_id' # primary key

    queryset.get.service # somehow fetch the service-variable from the record created in Proc-model.
    queryset.get.proc_id # somehow fetch the primary key from the record created in Proc-model.

   if service == 'sms':
        Sms.store(proc_id) # Not really important what this looks like. Only how i can get the proc_id and do whatever I want
   elif service == 'email':
        Sms.store(proc_id)
```

THanks for your help!

Comment: I believe you will need to override the `perform_create` method. You can then access the created instance upon calling the `serializer.save` method...

Comment: Thanks. Something like:          <code>def perform_create(self, serializer):
             q = serializer.save()
             q.proc_id # the primary key
             q.service # the other variable i need

Comment: Thanjs @drec4s it worked!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With thanks to @drec4s i solved it:

```
class ProcList(generics.CreateAPIView): # Endast Create för att skapa en proc
    queryset = Proc.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ProcSerializer
    permission_classes = (IsAdminOrReadOnly,)
    lookup_url_kwarg = 'proc_id'

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        q = serializer.save()
        TmpLogg(entry=q.service).save() # the other variable i need
```

I can now use service or proc_id how I like.